# SSRS Report Permiision Denied after Deploying to the Live Server

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a question regarding SSRS authentication. I have deployed my reports on a live server and after I access these reports using the live URL it shows "authentication failed" error. My purpose is that anyone from the universe can access the reports but how can I do that? i.e let everyone access that specific URL to see the reports.
I am using SQL Server Authentication here.

It runs fine when I run that application on the local server because it has rights to access the that report but the story starts when I try to access the report placed on the live server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want  allow public to  accuses it your report, you need to  use report viewer control, with out that is is very long process, to allow report server to be accessible to public. so the easy why is .

1. create new page and in  form tag  past bellow code

   ```
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="MainReportViewer" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                   Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos=" (Collection)" 
                   ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowBackButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" 
                   ShowPageNavigationControls="False" SizeToReportContent="True" 
                   ToolBarItemBorderColor="White" ToolBarItemHoverBackColor="White" 
                   WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%">
                   <ServerReport 
                       ReportServerUrl="" />
               </rsweb:ReportViewer>
   ```
2. below code help you to set you report path,  user name,password  and etc, that help to accuses your report, please past the below code in to  CA file

   protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   ```
       string UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsUserName"];
       string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsPassword"];
       string Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsDomain"];
       string ReportServerRoot = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsServerRoot"];
       string ReportServerPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsReportServerPath"];

       MainReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
       IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(UserName, Password, Domain);
       MainReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
       MainReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportServerRoot);
       MainReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportServerPath + "YourReportFileName";
   ```

   }

Comment: Giving Error on CustomReportCredentials function, Please Place the code for CustomReportCredentials... Waiting disperately

Comment: Please send me  your error message, because if  you give the right permission on report for that user Name  it will be fine. the above code work fine to.

Comment: Dear Beruk.Berhane Sorry for late replying  CustomReportCredentials() No definition is found for this when i write the line IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(UserName, Password, Domain);  it says CustomReportCredentials does not exists in the current context ....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delayed Reply. please find  customreportcreadentials class :-                                                            public class CustomReportCredentials : Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials
    {
        private string _UserName;
        private string _PassWord;
        private string _DomainName;

```
    public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
    {
        _UserName = UserName;
        _PassWord = PassWord;
        _DomainName = DomainName;
    }
    public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord)
    {
        _UserName = UserName;
        _PassWord = PassWord;
    }
    public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get { return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName); }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,
     out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        user = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```